# Unity, проблема с позицией объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: Луч и поинт]

Есть объект **point**:

```
public Transform point;
```

Выпускаю луч из его позиции, чтобы посмотреть, куда он направлен:

```
Debug.DrawRay(point.position, point.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), Color.red);
```

Но луч почему-то отображается в другом месте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, в чём тут может быть дело.

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, почему вы считаете, что `point` это позиция нужного вам объекта. Очевидно, что Unity так не считает.

Comment: т.к. я выбрал нужный мне объект в редакторе